# Mongodb data extraction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for some help on mongoDB. I'm doing a music Node project with mongodb and mongoose. I have 3 mongoose schema:

```js
// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    local: {
        username: String,
        password: String
    },
    spotify: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        username: String,
        profileUrl: String,
        email: String
    },
    deezer: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        username: String,
        profileUrl: String,
        email: String
    },
    youtube: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        displayName: String
    }
});

var musicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  author_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  url: String,
  file: String,
  title: String,
  artistName: String,
  deezerId: Number,
  itunesId: Number,
  position: Number,
  duration: Number,
  deezerAlbum: Number,
  discNumber: Number,
  album: String,
  releaseDate: Date,
  nbTracks: Number,
  genreId: Number,
  cover: String,
  genre: String,
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

var playlistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  author_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  contributor_id: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  tag: [String],
  importedPl: [String],
  musics: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
  syncImportedPlaylist: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  autoAddSimilarSong: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

To explain briefly here's the thing. I have a User, Music and Playlist Schemas.
I would like to extract one Playlist with all the Music and the User inside so that the final JS object look like that:

```js
{
  _id: someID
  name: String,
  author: {
    _id: someID
    local: {...},
    spotify: {...},
    deezer: {...},
    youtube: {...}
  },
  contributor: [{
    _id: someID
    local: {...},
    spotify: {...},
    deezer: {...},
    youtube: {...}
  }, {
    _id: someID
    local: {...},
    spotify: {...},
    deezer: {...},
    youtube: {...}
  }],
  musics_ids: [{
  _id: someID
  author: {
    _id: someID
    local: {...},
    spotify: {...},
    deezer: {...},
    youtube: {...}
  },
  url: String,
  file: String,
  title: String,
  ...allTheMusicSchemaInfo...: ...
}],
  ...allThePlaylistSchemaInfo...: ...
}
```

I would like to replace ..._id fied by the data itself (ie replace author_id by user data, same for musics_ids).

Edit: Answer here (thx @matheusds): https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727050/7841588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference documents from other collections you could use `populate` method described in more details [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

This method automatically replaces the paths in the documents by documents from other collections.

Comment: Thx verry much this is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Please, mark the answer as the right one to help other people out when looking this thread! :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :/